# Plugin de botón flotante para Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Necesito crear un botón fijo en la parte inferior derecha del sitio web. Algo parecido a esta página: http://www.geteco.es/

Estoy buscando plugins, pero la mayoria son botones con iconos, botones de redes sociales... o simplemente no puedo posicionarlos como quiero. El único que he encontrado que me podría ayudar es un plugin llamado Floatton, pero es de pago.

¿Alguien conoce algún plugin que haga lo que busco o alguna forma de hacerlo por código?

Comment: No hace falta que te disculpes, es una pregunta sobre maquetación web que es un tema válido en [SOes](http://es.stackoverflow.com/), quizá no lo sabías porque buscabas un plugin para hacer algo que básicamente es un tema de HTML y CSS

Comment: Yo la verdad que tengo el mismo problema...[sagokireformas](https://sagoki.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No conozco plugins para wordpress, pero te puedo poner algún ejemplo sencillo de como crearlo en código.

Solo necesitas que en la capa que quieras, ponerle en sus estilos "position:fixed" para que no se mueva al hacer scroll y la posición "bottom: 0; right:15px;".

Te dejo un ejemplo como el de la página que has pasado.

```css
body{
   /*Altura para probar que este fijado la capa*/
   height: 2000px;
}
#fixed-bottom{
    /*Para fijar la posicion de la capa*/  
    position: fixed;
    /** colocacion de la capa */
    bottom: 0;
    right: 15px;
    
    width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ff8d00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="fixed-bottom">
  <span>Estoy fijado baja el scroll</span>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: He implementado el código en una web y en desktop es genial pero en la móvil, aunque aparece en la parte inferior como fija, es como si estuviese en una capa inferior y "transparente" con lo que no hay forma de pulsar sobre el botón para ir a la página de contacto. ***¿Sabríais decirme cómo integrar el código para que funcione también en móvil?*** Gracias